# Using RSolve correctly

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I am having problems persuading *Mathematica* to solve even the simplest recurrence relations.

As an example, how would you do the following?

```
RSolve[{q[i] == 1 + (i - 1)*q[i - 1], q[0] == 0}, q[i], {i}]
```

**Addendum**

Another problem, isn't this exactly equivalent? It seems *Mathematica* can't solve this.

```
RSolve[{q[i, k] == 1 + ((i - 1))*q[i - 1, k - 1], q[1, 1] == 1}, q[i, k], {i, k}]
```

Comment: I think it's the initial condition. Remove it and try again. If you notice from the recursion eq. the value of $q$ at $0$ doesn't matter.

Comment: If you run your code, the returned error ("...the given boundary conditions lead to an empty solution.") is pretty helpful.

Comment: If you want to use an initial condition use the _natural one_, `q[1]==1`.

Comment: That seems very unhelpful of Mathematica to me. q[1]==1 gives a useful answer.  How would you know which initial conditions it will be happy with?

Comment: @Anush if the result when using `q[1] == 1` is what you want, `E Gamma[i, 1]`, you should note that `E Gamma[i, 1]` with `i = 0` is ~= 0.596347, *not* zero.  Or do you want something else?

Comment: Thanks. I am only interested in integer $i \geq 1$. I see that defining $q[0]$ implies to Mathematica that that it should provide a general solution that holds for $i=0$ as well which it can't do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The incomplete Euler gamma function is defined with :

$$\Gamma(a,z)=\int_{z}^{\infty} t^{a-1} e^{-t} d t$$

You can observe that the integral is defined for `Re[a] > 0` :

```
Integrate[t^(a - 1) Exp[-t], {t, 0, Infinity}]
```

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[ Gamma[a], Re[a] > 0]
> ```

while for `a == 0` this does not converge.

Starting with your recurrence relation one easily finds : $q(1)=1,\; q(2)=2,\; q(3) = 5,\; q(4)=16$.

Taking the initial condition $q(1)=1\;$ instead of $q(0)=0\;$ we find :

```
RSolve[{ q[n] == 1 + (n - 1) q[n - 1], q[1] == 1}, q[n], n]
```

> ```
>  {{q[n] -> E Gamma[n, 1]}}
> ```

This is  correct  since we can simplfy it with `FullSimplify`, even though one cannot simplify the original result `E Gamma[n, 1]` directly for all natural numbers.

```
FullSimplify[ Table[E Gamma[n, 1], {n, 8}], n ∈ Range[8]]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 5, 16, 65, 326, 1957, 13700}
> ```

**Ad addendum**

Another recurrence relation is clearly not equivalent to the original one.  That relation binds values for equal `k` and `i` only, not for all natural `i` and `k` like you seem to expect.  `RSolve` perhaps will be updated with more options in the future but they should be appropriate to satisfy only perfectly well posed conditions.

You can see that your original initial condition (for `i == 0`) has been inappropriate to satisfy the final result in terms of the Euler gamma function.

Comment: Thank you. You are quite right about the addendum (and I was wrong). I needed to have a way to specify that $i=k$. In terms of the initial condition $i==0$ although I see your point I don't think I agree. A perfectly good answer would be if $n \geq 1$ then $q[n]= e$ Gamma$[n,1]$, if $n =0$ then $q[n]=0$ wouldn't it?

Comment: @Anush `Mathematica` is 25 years old, while `RSolve` only `10`, you shouldn't expect perfect answers so far. Nevertheless this function is quite good. Another point is that any software system cannot be free of inconsistencies.

Comment: Of course. Maybe it would be nice to have a central wiki for these feature requests/bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Your sequence is

```
q[0] = 0;
q[i_] := 1 + (i - 1) q[i - 1]
```

And I used the following code to find some terms for the above sequence.

```
For[ k = 1, k < 12, k++, Print[ q [ k ] ] ]
```

And the output is

> ```
> 1
> 2
> 5
> 16
> 65
> 326
> 1957
> 13700
> 109601
> 986410
> 9864101
> ```

These numbers are "Total number of arrangements of a set with n elements". You can find them [here](http://oeis.org/A000522).

Comment: `RecurrenceTable` would be a good way to get the list of values: `RecurrenceTable[{q[n] == 1 + (n - 1) q[n - 1], q[0] == 0}, q, {n, 1, 10}]`

Comment: The question concerns a general formula form `RSolve`, not just writing down several  consequtive values.